# Tensorflow CustomEstimator DNNRegressor label_dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am currently fairly new to tensorflow and I'm trying to predict the position of a particle based on it's position in past time steps.

my features looks like this:

```
    X_0    X_1    X_2    X_3    X_4    Y_0    Y_1    Y_2    Y_3    Y_4
19  650.0  651.0  652.0  653.0  654.0  128.3  135.9  143.5  151.1  158.7
16  647.0  648.0  649.0  650.0  651.0  105.5  113.1  120.7  128.3  135.9
...
```

and my labeles look like this:

```
     LabelX  LabelY
19   655.0   166.3
16   652.0   143.5
...
```

as you can see my Labels are 2-Dimensional. My first attempt uses tensorflows premade estimator `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor` and by giving it the argument `label_dimension=2` during creation this works well.

Now I'd like to do the same with a custom estimator.
Sadly the tutorials on the tensorflow site are all using Classifier instead of Regressors and the only example I've been able to find online is [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/get_started/regression/custom_regression.py), but they only use a one-dimensional output.

I've been experimenting quite a bit, but I wasn't able to get any progress.
I'm fairly certain that I have to change line 41

```
output_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=top, units=1)
```

But if I do that, I can't get the rest of the file to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.

you can find my code [here](https://gist.github.com/Strandtasche/836b8cf59cefffeae4b219596e9cfa5c).

```
import tensorflow as tf


def myCustomEstimator(features, labels, mode, params):
    """Modell funktion für Custom Estimator (DNN Regression)"""

    # Input Layer
    top = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params["feature_columns"])

    # basierend auf hidden Units wird die Netztopologie aufgebaut
    for units in params.get("hidden_units", [20]):
        top = tf.layers.dense(inputs=top, units=units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        if "dropout" in params.keys() and params["dropout"] != 0:
            top = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=top, rate=params["dropout"], training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

    # lineares output layer mit 2 Neuronen für die 2 Koordinaten
    output_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=top, units=2)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        # In `PREDICT` mode we only need to return predictions.
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode, predictions={"predictions": output_layer})

    average_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), output_layer)
    tf.summary.scalar("average_loss", average_loss)

    MSE = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), output_layer)
    tf.summary.scalar('error', MSE[1])

    # Pre-made estimators use the total_loss instead of the average,
    # so report total_loss for compatibility.
    batch_size = tf.shape(labels)[0]
    total_loss = tf.to_float(batch_size) * average_loss

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = params.get("optimizer", tf.train.AdamOptimizer)
        optimizer = optimizer(params.get("learning_rate", None))
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss=average_loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode, loss=total_loss, train_op=train_op)


    # In evaluation mode we will calculate evaluation metrics.
    assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL

    # Calculate root mean squared error
    rmse = tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), output_layer)

    # Add the rmse to the collection of evaluation metrics.
    eval_metrics = {"rmse": rmse, "average_loss": MSE}

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        # Report sum of error for compatibility with pre-made estimators
        loss=total_loss,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics)
```